# Driver do sql nao encontrado

Tags: sql-server, driver

Estou com o PHP versão 5.6.25 instalei com sucesso a extensão do mssql e aparece na relação de extensão do PHP marcado que esta executando a seguinte extensão
PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_56_TS  mas quando eu dou um phpinfo()  ela não fica disponível não mostra que esta rodando, ja instalei o driver Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 para SQL Server® - Windows reiniciai a maquina e nao aparece disponível no phpinfo, mas mostra que esta instalado na extensões do PHP como resolver isto?

obrigado
Joab

Comment: Já verifico se esta faltando alguma dll ou se a dll esta apontada no arquivo de configuração do PHP? Aparece algum erro quando tenta usar este recurso?

Comment: Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre o site.

Comment: a DLL esta no diretório de extensões do PHP, não da erro nenhum e quando clico para ver as extensões instaladas no PHP, ela aparece que esta instalada normal, mas quando eu rodo  o phpinfo() as extensão novas instaladas  não aparece na relação de extensões instadas,